# Unable to extract table from the ESPN website

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to extract a table from the ESPN website using the code below, however I am unable to extract the whole table and paste the whole table in the new csv file. I am getting error as `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_csv'`

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time
import requests
service = Service(r"C:\Users\Sai Ram\Documents\Python\Driver\chromedriver.exe")

def get_driver():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_argument("disable-dev-shm-usage")
    options.add_argument("no-sandbox")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_argument("disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = service, options = options)
    driver.get("https://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/records/team/match_results.html?class=3;id=2022;type=year")
    return driver

def main():
    get_driver()
    url = "https://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/records/team/match_results.html?class=3;id=2022;type=year"

    html = requests.get(url).content
    df_list = pd.read_html(html)
    df=df_list

    df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Sai Ram\Documents\Power BI\End to End T-20 World Cup DashBoard\CSV Data\scappying.csv')


main()
```

Could you please help in resolving this issue and if possible suggest me the best way to extract data using web scrapping code in python.

Comment: so `df_list` should be a list of dataframes, you probably want to a) check it's not empty, then b) select just one of them to call `to_csv` on

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
import pandas as pd
url = "https://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/records/team/match_results.html?class=3;id=2022;type=year"
df = pd.read_html(url)[0] # <- this index is important 
df.head()
```

Output

```
    Team 1  Team 2  Winner  Margin  Ground  Match Date  Scorecard
0   West Indies     England     West Indies     9 wickets   Bridgetown  Jan 22, 2022    T20I # 1453
1   West Indies     England     England     1 run   Bridgetown  Jan 23, 2022    T20I # 1454
2   West Indies     England     West Indies     20 runs     Bridgetown  Jan 26, 2022    T20I # 1455
3   West Indies     England     England     34 runs     Bridgetown  Jan 29, 2022    T20I # 1456
4   West Indies     England     West Indies     17 runs     Bridgetown  Jan 30, 2022    T20I # 1457
```

To save your dataframe as a CSV file:

```
df.to_csv("your_data_file.csv")
```

By loading the webpage into pandas you get 2 dataframes (in this case for this particular site). The first dataframe is the one you want (at least I understand this from you post) with the large table of results. The second one is a smaller list. So by indexing the table with `[0]` you retrieve the first dataframe.

You get the attribute error because you try to treat the list of (2) dataframes as a dataframe.